# SQL to find two people who participated in the most meetings together

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have three tables which are as follows:

[image: Schema]

from this I have to find the two people who participated in the most meetings together.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.) Also show us your current query attempt. [mcve]

Comment: This screen capture comes directly from an online code test, and is a violation of the agreement you made at the beginning of the test

Comment: cheating on a test

Answer (score 3):

This should get you going.

**Sample data**

```
create table person
(
  id int,
  name nvarchar(10)
);    
insert into person (id, name) values
(1, 'Alice'),
(2, 'Bob'),
(3, 'Charlie'),
(4, 'David'),
(5, 'Eric');

create table meeting
(
  id int,
  title nvarchar(30)
);    
insert into meeting (id, title) values
(100, 'Corporate training'),
(200, 'Weekly sales'),
(300, 'Welcome introduction'),
(400, 'Evaluation');

create table participant
(
  idMeeting int,
  idPerson int
);    
insert into participant (idMeeting, idPerson) values
(100,1), (100,2), (100,3), (100,4), (100,5),
(200,1), (200,2),
         (300,2), (300,3), (300,4),
                  (400,3),          (400,5),
                  (500,3),          (500,5);
```

**Solution**

Find shared meetings by joining participant rows with the same meeting id (`pa2.idMeeting = pa1.idMeeting`).

```
select me.title,
       pe1.name,
       pe2.name
from participant pa1
join participant pa2
  on  pa2.idMeeting = pa1.idMeeting
  and pa2.idPerson <> pa1.idPerson
join meeting me
  on me.id = pa1.idMeeting
join person pe1
  on pe1.id = pa1.idPerson
join person pe2
  on pe2.id = pa2.idPerson;
```

This will give you many duplicates such as `Alice` went to the `Corporate training` with `Bob` and `Bob` went to the `Corporate training` with `Alice`. These are of course the same occurance. We can filter out duplicates by saying that not only do participants have to be different (`pa2.idPerson <> pa1.idPerson`), they also have to be "sorted" (`pa2.idPerson > pa1.idPerson`).

```
select me.title,
       pe1.name,
       pe2.name
from participant pa1
join participant pa2
  on  pa2.idMeeting = pa1.idMeeting
  and pa2.idPerson > pa1.idPerson
join meeting me
  on me.id = pa1.idMeeting
join person pe1
  on pe1.id = pa1.idPerson
join person pe2
  on pe2.id = pa2.idPerson;
```

This gives you all unique combinations for all meetings. The meeting details can be excluded from the result (removed `join meeting`). Grouping on the unique combinations (`group by pe1.name, pe2.name`) gives a count (`count(1) as SharedMeetings`) to work with.

```
select pe1.name as Person1,
       pe2.name as Person2,
       count(1) as SharedMeetings
from participant pa1
join participant pa2
  on  pa2.idMeeting = pa1.idMeeting
  and pa2.idPerson > pa1.idPerson
join person pe1
  on pe1.id = pa1.idPerson
join person pe2
  on pe2.id = pa2.idPerson
group by pe1.name,
         pe2.name
order by SharedMeetings desc,
         pe1.name,
         pe2.name;
```

**Result**

For the final query:

```
Person1  Person2  SharedMeetings
-------  -------  --------------
Charlie  Eric     3
Alice    Bob      2
Bob      Charlie  2
Bob      David    2
Charlie  David    2
Alice    Charlie  1
Alice    David    1
Alice    Eric     1
Bob      Eric     1
David    Eric     1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=49e1d294be2e324fde95c50c316385cb) to see things in action (with intermediate versions).

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a self-join on meeting:

```
select top (1) with ties p1.person_id, p2.person_id,
       count(*) as num_meetings
from participant p1 join
     participant p2
     on p1.meeting_id = p2.meeting_id
group by p1.person_id, p2.person_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

This returns the person ids, which answers your question.  If you want more information about the persons from the `person` table, then you can join such information in.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  TOP(1)
        partnerA.person_id,
        partnerB.person_id,
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM    meeting
            WHERE   EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM participant WHERE participant.meeting_id = meeting.meeting_id AND participant.person_id = partnerA.person_id)
            AND     EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM participant WHERE participant.meeting_id = meeting.meeting_id AND participant.person_id = partnerB.person_id)
        )   AS      participated_together

FROM        person  partnerA
CROSS JOIN  person  partnerB
WHERE       partnerA.person_id  <   partnerB.person_id

ORDER BY    participated_together   DESC
```

This shows only 1 pair with most meetings together,

but you can change it to show more - just change the TOP(1)

Answer (score 0):

This is just in case there are multiple pairs of people who attended same maximum number of meetings

```
with t1 as (select a.person_id, b.person_id, count(*) as cnt
       from meetings a join meetings b
       on a.meeting_id = b.meeting_id
       and a.person_id < b.person_id
       group by 1, 2)
       
       select concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) as person1,
       concat(b.first_name, ' ', b.last_name) as person2
       from t1 join person a
       on t1.person_id = a.person_id
       join person b
       on t1.person_id = b.person_id
       where cnt = (select max(cnt) from t1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
WITH OUTE AS
(SELECT CONCAT(D.FIRST_NAME,' ',D.LAST_NAME) FIRST_PERSON,
    CONCAT(E.FIRST_NAME,' ',E.LAST_NAME) SECOND_PERSON,
    C.TITLE
  FROM  PARTICIPANT A
    JOIN PARTICIPANT B
       ON A.MEETING_ID=B.MEETING_ID
      AND A.PERSON_ID !=B.PERSON_ID
      AND A.PERSON_ID < B.PERSON_ID
    JOIN PERSON D
       ON A.PERSON_ID=D.PERSON_ID
    JOIN PERSON E
       ON B.PERSON_ID=E.PERSON_ID
    JOIN MEETING C
       ON A.MEETING_ID=C.MEETING_ID
 ),

OUTE2 AS

(SELECT FIRST_PERSON,
    SECOND_PERSON,
    COUNT(*) MEETINGS
FROM OUTE
GROUP BY FIRST_PERSON,
         SECOND_PERSON)
,
OUTE3 AS
(SELECT X.FIRST_PERSON,
    X.SECOND_PERSON,
    X.TITLE,
    Y.MEETINGS
FROM OUTE X 
    JOIN OUTE2 Y
         ON X.FIRST_PERSON=Y.FIRST_PERSON
        AND X.SECOND_PERSON=Y.SECOND_PERSON
    ORDER BY Y.MEETINGS DESC)

SELECT FIRST_PERSON,
         SECOND_PERSON,
         TITLE
FROM OUTE3
    WHERE MEETINGS = (SELECT MEETINGS FROM OUTE3 LIMIT 1)
    ORDER BY TITLE;
```

The solution is to be improved.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In most cases, code-only answers suffer from a lack of explanation; consider explaining how this answers the question to add value for other users down the road.

Comment: @ConnorLow, Thanks for your comment. I will add a complete explanation soon in my next edit.