# Why am I getting syntax error in SQL Server 'in' clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written a query in SQL Server and am getting an error.

Code:

```
with cte as (
    select pe1.name as P1,
        pe2.name as P2,
        m.title as T
    from participant pa1
    join participant pa2 on pa2.idMeeting = pa1.idMeeting
        and pa2.idPerson > pa1.idPerson
    join person pe1 on pe1.id = pa1.idPerson
    join person pe2 on pe2.id = pa2.idPerson
    join meeting m on m.id = pa1.idMeeting
),
cte_meet_max as (
    select count(*) cnt, P1,P2
    from cte
    group by P1,P2    
)
select *
from cte 
where (P1,P2) in (
    select P1,P2 
    from cte_meet_max 
    where cnt = (select max(cnt) from cte_meet_max)
);
```

Error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Desired result:

[image: desired result]

Can we put two columns with 'in' clause in SQL Server?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I tried solving the question posted before [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66650310/sql-to-find-two-people-who-participated-in-the-most-meetings-together)

Comment: SQL Server simply doesn't support this. You will need to rewrite it to an EXISTS condition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  How to do that!

Comment: Give it a go an see how you get on.

Comment: @DaleK How can EXISTS replace the given condition?

Comment: I don't understand the logic... sample data + desired results would clarify.

Comment: @Anjali With correlated behavior, where the subquery compares `(in.col1 = out.col1 AND in.col2= out.col2)` along with the `MAX` restriction `AND in.cnt = (SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM ... )`.

Comment: Sample data:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66650310/sql-to-find-two-people-who-participated-in-the-most-meetings-together

Comment: @DaleK see edited question for desired result

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text. And we need to see what your starting data is also.

Comment: To recap: while `IN` with tuples is standard SQL and several DBMS support this, SQL Server does not, so you must find another way. Every `IN` clause can be replaced with an `EXISTS` clause, so this is the way to go here. The only drawback: `EXISTS` is often slighly less readable than `IN`.

Comment: Remark: Pairs like "`(a,b) in`" are supported in Oracle, but not in SQL Server.

Comment: @SQLPolice: that syntax is part of the SQL standard and not exclusive to Oracle. It's also supported by Postgres, MySQL, DB2, SQLite and several others.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did not write that it is exclusive to Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An EXISTS condition is the proper way to rewrite this in SQL Server:

```
with cte as (
    select pe1.name as P1,
        pe2.name as P2,
        m.title as T
    from participant pa1
    join participant pa2 on pa2.idMeeting = pa1.idMeeting
        and pa2.idPerson > pa1.idPerson
    join person pe1 on pe1.id = pa1.idPerson
    join person pe2 on pe2.id = pa2.idPerson
    join meeting m on m.id = pa1.idMeeting
),
cte_meet_max as (
    select count(*) cnt, P1,P2
    from cte
    group by P1,P2    
)
select *
from cte 
where exists (
    select *
    from cte_meet_max m1
    where m1.cnt = (select max(m2.cnt) from cte_meet_max m2)
      and m1.p1 = cte.p1
      and m1.p2 = cte.p2
)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  @Anjali: Please remove the checkmark from the other answer and check this answer as the correct one.

Comment: @SQLPolice Thanks. It was a clear solution

Answer (score 1):

Optional solution:

I used detail from both questions here.

Thanks to @Sander for the initial test case.  I've made a tiny change to insert the missing meeting (id = 500), in case someone wanted to join with that table, and I've created a fiddle to show the test case:

[Working Test Case for SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=79aaf01535ed6f962eb7b86fbb36d0ff)

The solution counts the meetings each pair of participants have in common.

Additionally, I use a window function to, in the same query expression, find the `MAX` count over the entire set of results, avoiding one separate step.

As a result, the last query expression only needs to compare the current `cnt` to the `max_cnt`, available in each row, without needing correlated behavior.

Most are assuming the `person` names are unique.  I also made that assumption in the first query, but used the primary keys (or would have been PKs, if constraints were created) in the second query.

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT pe1.name as p1
             , pe2.name as p2
             , COUNT(*) AS cnt
             , MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS max_cnt
          FROM participant pa1
          JOIN participant pa2
            ON pa2.idMeeting = pa1.idMeeting
           AND pa2.idPerson  > pa1.idPerson
          JOIN person pe1 on pe1.id = pa1.idPerson
          JOIN person pe2 on pe2.id = pa2.idPerson
         GROUP BY pe1.name, pe2.name
     )
SELECT *
  FROM cte
 WHERE cnt = max_cnt
;
```

If we don't need person names, we can avoid a little work:

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT pa1.idPerson as p1
             , pa2.idPerson as p2
             , COUNT(*) AS cnt
             , MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS max_cnt
          FROM participant pa1
          JOIN participant pa2
            ON pa2.idMeeting = pa1.idMeeting
           AND pa2.idPerson  > pa1.idPerson
         GROUP BY pa1.idPerson, pa2.idPerson
     )
SELECT *
  FROM cte
 WHERE cnt = max_cnt
;
```

Comment: @Anjali . . . Window functions are the right way to write this query.

Answer (score 0):

You should only concatenate P1 and P2 in you're where clause

```
with cte as (
        select pe1.name as P1,
            pe2.name as P2,
            m.title as T
        from participant pa1
        join participant pa2 on pa2.idMeeting = pa1.idMeeting
            and pa2.idPerson > pa1.idPerson
        join person pe1 on pe1.id = pa1.idPerson
        join person pe2 on pe2.id = pa2.idPerson
        join meeting m on m.id = pa1.idMeeting
    ),
    cte_meet_max as (
        select count(*) cnt, P1,P2
        from cte
        group by P1,P2    
    ),
    meet_max as (select P1,P2
        from cte_meet_max 
        where cnt = (select max(cnt) from cte_meet_max))
    select *
    from cte ,meet_max
    where cte.P1=meet_max.P1 and cte.P2=meet_max.P2
        
    );
```

Comment: Evolve - there is no good reason to be using (or recommending) the use of [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)